# Environment Instances in in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, environments, styles

If we defined a custom environment, say `\begin{example}...\end{example}`, I wanted to ask for help with displaying the instances of `example` in the table of contents (ToC) as most appropriate subsections.

For example, for an environment similar to that of [[Overleaf, Write your own package]](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Writing_your_own_package),

```
\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{
  \refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
  \noindent \textbf{Example~\thesection.\theexample.} \textsc{#1.}
  \rmfamily
}{\medskip}
```

how could we modify it to transform the ToC in,

```latex
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\begin{example}[First] An introductory example.
\end{example}
\begin{example}[Second] Another example.
\end{example}

\section{Explanation}
\begin{example}[Third] A more advanced example.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

into,

```
Introduction ... 1
  1.1 First .... 1
  1.2 Second ... 1
Content ........ 1
  2.1 Third .... 1
```

[image: example instances]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example to add the example title as subsection level entry. I also tweak the env definition a little bit, to put the env contents in a group and add `\par` after the env:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{subsection}{\textbf{Example~\thesection.\theexample.}\quad\textsc{#1.}}{\thepage}{}}%
  \bgroup\noindent\textbf{Example~\thesection.\theexample.} \textsc{#1.}%
  \rmfamily
}{\egroup\par\medskip}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\clearpage

\section{Introduction}
\begin{example}[First longer name of the example with longer name]
An introductory example
\end{example}
\subsection{test}
\begin{example}[Second] Another example.
\end{example}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{100}
\section{Explanation}
\subsection{test}
\begin{example}[Third] A more advanced example.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much!